# How can i add object with javascript to this json example?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

How can i add "name_3" to this json?

```
    json = {
        "name_1": [{
                "kind": "podcast",
                "artistId": 139918600
            },
            {
                "kind": "podcast",
                "artistId": 139918600
            }
        ],
        "name_2": [{
                "kind": "podcast",
                "artistId": 139918600
            },
            {
                "kind": "podcast",
                "artistId": 139918600
            }
        ]
    }
```

`var name_3 = {"kind": "audio","artistId": 4691754},{"kind": "video","artistId": 139918600}`

i want to access it like this `json.name_3[0]artistId`
Later, i will have to check if it already exist and rewrite it, or delete it from a custom function

Comment: `"name_1":` **[** `...` and `"name_2":` **[** `...` , *but* `"name_3":` **{** `...` Apples and oranges

Comment: I created a node module https://github.com/onigetoc/virtual-storage to make i virtual storage when you do not have access cookies, LocalStorage and a bd. I did it for my Dialogflow skill.

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets `json["name_3"] =` or with a variable `json[name] =` or dot notation `json.name_3 =`

```js
const json = {
  "name_1": [{
      "kind": "podcast",
      "artistId": 139918600
    },
    {
      "kind": "podcast",
      "artistId": 139918600
    }
  ],
  "name_2": [{
      "kind": "podcast",
      "artistId": 139918600
    },
    {
      "kind": "podcast",
      "artistId": 139918600
    }
  ]
};


const name = "name_3";
json[name] = [{
  "kind": "movie",
  "artistId": 123456780
}];
console.log(json[name][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let json = {
    "name_1": [{
        "kind": "podcast",
        "artistId": 139918600
    },
    {
        "kind": "podcast",
        "artistId": 139918600
    }
    ],
    "name_2": [{
        "kind": "podcast",
        "artistId": 139918600
    },
    {
        "kind": "podcast",
        "artistId": 139918600
    }
    ]
}

let name_3 = [{ "kind": "audio", "artistId": 4691754 }, { "kind": "video", "artistId": 139918600 }];

json["name_3"] = name_3;
//or
//json.name_3 = name_3;

//access it:
console.log(json.name_3 && json.name_3[0].artistId);

//check if it's there:
if (json.name_3) console.log("It's there");
else console.log("Not there")

//delete it:
delete json.name_3;
```

Comment: Great thank you, i was not far but my problem is my object was not in bracket [] to begin with.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem actually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to achieve this.

```js
var json = {
        "name_1": [{
                "kind": "podcast",
                "artistId": 139918600
            },
            {
                "kind": "podcast",
                "artistId": 139918600
            }
        ],
        "name_2": [{
                "kind": "podcast",
                "artistId": 139918600
            },
            {
                "kind": "podcast",
                "artistId": 139918600
            }
        ]
    };
    
var name_3 = [{"kind": "audio","artistId": 4691754},{"kind": "video","artistId": 139918600}];

console.log({...json, name_3});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your json has to be string not object, then you can parse it to object via JSON.parse() method. Then you can add your new element to object and make it json format again using JSON.stringify() method.

```js
const json = `{
        "name_1": [{
                "kind": "podcast",
                "artistId": 139918600
            },
            {
                "kind": "podcast",
                "artistId": 139918600
            }
        ],
        "name_2": [{
                "kind": "podcast",
                "artistId": 139918600
            },
            {
                "kind": "podcast",
                "artistId": 139918600
            }
        ]
    }`
    const name3 = [{kind: "audio",artistId: 4691754},{kind: "video",artistId: 139918600}];
    let obj = JSON.parse(json);
    Object.assign(obj, name3);
    const newJson = JSON.stringify(obj)
```